# Synchronize processes by locking a file

Tags: perl

One of my scripts is installing a component. When run in parallel, the same script tries to install the same component, so I thought about synchronizing the process by locking a file while the script is installing and wait while other script is installing something.

The code would look like this:

```
# this will create a file handler on a file from TEMP dir with the
# name of the component; if it doesn't exist in TEMP dir, it will create it

my $file = $ENV{"TEMP"}. "\\" . $componentName;
open (my $fh, ">", "$file") or die "Couldn't open file!";

# this will apply an exclusive lock  meaning that if another process
# already locked the file, it will wait until the lock is removed

flock($fh, 2) or die "Failed to lock the file";

# install the component..

# closing the file handle automatically removes the lock
close $fh;
```

I am concerned about the situation when a script locks the file and is starting the installation and the second script comes and tries to create a file handle on the locked file. I didn't see any errors, but I don't want to miss something.

Will there be a problem with this?

Comment: It's probably better for readability if you use the named constants instead of "2" in you `flock` call. Also you probably want to have default value for `$ENV{TEMP}`, and check that your `open` is successful. You probably want to check the return value of `flock` as well.

Comment: @jcaron You are right, thanks for the suggestions, I am using explicit constants name, also treating the exceptions which may occur while opening or locking the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that's important to remember is - the 'open' will work in either case, because that doesn't test the lock. It's the `flock` operation that will block until the lock is released.

And this should work just fine, although once the lock *is* released - you might want to check if you still need to run the install, unless you don't really care about doing it twice - e.g. if the rest of the script makes use of/relies upon it.

Also - are there other sources of 'installing' that aren't your script, that could cause the same problem? A lock is an advisory thing.

It would be a style improvement in your program to also:

- Test `$ENV{'TEMP'}` to see that it exists, and default (or fail) if it doesn't.
- `use Fcntl qw ( :flock );` because then you can `flock ( $fh, LOCK_EX );` to make it clear you're taking an exclusive lock.
- You appear to be using `\\` as a file separator. That's probably better if you used something like [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) to do that, for portability reasons.
- You can use a `LOCK_NB` for nonblocking: `flock ( $fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB )` and then just skip if it's locked.

Comment: You are right, I am checking afterwards if the component was already installed by another script.

Comment: This is the only concern which I had, if the lock affects or not the `open` function

Comment: @JohnDoe: You could just [read about it](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html)

Comment: @Sobrique: I would add that calls to `flock` shouldn't be made using *magic numbers*, and that `use Fcntl ':flock'` provides some useful identifiers for the constants that may need to be passed.

Comment: About last point, I intentionately use a blocking lock. Because each script needs to use later the component which it installs. And if 2 scripts are trying to install the same component, first one runs and starts the installation, the second comes and finds the file locked. If it skips, it will try to access the component which isn't installed yet by the first script. With the blocking lock, I'm creating a "queue" a-like system.

Comment: Also, thank you for the style improvements suggestions. They are really helpfull and I will defently implement them.

Answer (score 2):

A lock doesn't prevent the file from being opened or modified; it prevents it from being locked.

This means the `open` won't fail, and it will clobber the file even if it's locked and still being used. If the lock is meant to protect access to the file (i.e. if the programs actually write to the locked file), you want to use `sysopen` to avoid clobbering the file if it already exists<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX O_CREAT O_WRONLY );

# Open the file without clobbering it, creating it if necessary.
sysopen(my $fh, $qfn, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)
   or die($!);

# Wait for the file to become available.
flock($fh, LOCK_EX)
   or die($!);

truncate($fh, 0)
   or die($!);

...
```

or

```
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_NB O_CREAT O_WRONLY );

# Open the file without clobbering it, creating it if necessary.
sysopen(my $fh, $qfn, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)
   or die($!);

# Check if the file is locked.
flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)
   or die($!{EWOULDBLOCK} ? "File already in use\n" : $!);

truncate($fh, 0)
   or die($!);

...
```

---

1. You could also use `open(my $fh, '>>', $qfn)` if you don't mind having the file in append mode.

Comment: Great, thank you.  So I _can_ open a file first and then wait, with `sysopen`.  I take it that then the `open` for reading is fine (then wait).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very good explanation! I will ignore the clobber  issue because it isn't the important piece in my algorithm. The important part is to synchronize the installations, the file is just a pawn in this chess game. I use it just as a flag. While it is locked, don't do any installation. If the file isn't lock, then I can install.

Comment: Ah yes. I'll add a comment about that to my answer.